# Java checkstyle error "Declaring variables, return values or parameters of type 'Integer' is not allowed."

Tags: java, variables, integer, checkstyle

A straightforward piece of code

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 10;
        Integer[] x = new Integer[N];  // checkstyle error
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            x[i] = (Integer) i;
    }
}
```

"Declaring variables, return values or parameters of type 'Integer' is not allowed."

Any thoughts?

Comment: it works perfectly for me. beside outboxing and unboxing will be done automatically.

Comment: hmm, i'm using checkstyle 5.5

Comment: it's a tool to check coding standard. http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html

Comment: Apparently using Integers is not generally acceptable to the coding standard being checked.  Why that may be I haven't a clue, but a coding standard is a coding standard -- you may honor it or ignore it, depending on how much your job depends on it.

Comment: Just use a generic `int`

Comment: *Why that may be I haven't a clue* - Maybe an education scenario, where they want to avoid having to deal with students being confused because incrementing an `Integer` has no effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This check looks like it's part of the [illegal type](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalType) check suite.  Someone had decided to configure Checkstyle in such a way that you weren't permitted to use `Integer`.

That aside, the usage of `Integer` here is unnecssary.  You can do the *exact same* thing with a primitive `int` and an `int[]` instead.

Comment: Nothing universal from what I've heard of, although there are teams that don't like autoboxing due to overhead or for some other reason.

Comment: This is definitely not a standard rule, but was specifically configured in your case.